# Create an ELF file where the section after the .text section is very distant from the .text section

Tags: linux, assembly, elf

I need to test a program I'm writing against a pathological corner case. To do that, I want to compile an assembly file so that the .text section will be far away from the section that follows it.

That is, I want to have something like this when I run `objdump -h` on the compiled file:

```
  12 .text         00000204  0000000000400400  0000000000400400  00000400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  13 .fini         00000016  0000000000500000  0000000000500000  00000604  2**2
```

Note how there's a very wide gap between the end of one section and the start of the other.
I've modified the output of the command to illustrate what I want, so if something in the output doesn't make sense it's because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the assembler with `-Wl,--section-start=.text=0x100000 -Wl,--section-start=.data=0x400000` did the work for me.

Answer (score 2):

... and you want to know how to force the linker to create a file like this one?

You may write the link script manually and use the "-T filename" option of "ld" (which is the "-Wl,-T,filename" option of "gcc").

Comment: I have no idea what to put in a link script like that.

I know I can use --section-start to change the starting location of sections, but doing this for two sections doesn't work.